# Visual Studio Code Intellisense for style CSS in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to get autocomplete or suggestions or intellisense or something for CSS when developing in React?

[image: example]

For example, when I write something like this I want to be able to see all the possibilities for that CSS property. I know that I can get this if I use `.css` files but sometimes I want to use inline CSS for something and it's really annoying that I have to google every time to see what I can use.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use this. (Similiar to `StyleSheet.create()` in React Native):
https://github.com/sutanlab/react-styles-hook

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some extension that will help you because CSS keeps getting better day by day. So, the maximum you can achieve is create a cheatsheet and use that for every project.

You can install `IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML` by `Zignd`. It is VS Code extension that loads your CSS on program launch and provides autocomplete for that.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, this only works for class names, I need something that works for CSS properties

Comment: It scans the whole project and maintain cache. So, it means if you used a margin class regularly it will be shown by autocomplete.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. VScode has great intellisense when editing a .css file or .html file within <style> tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Styled-Components** then try using this Extension:

Extension Name: **vscode-styled-components** by **Julien Poissonnier**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

Answer (score 1):

Open VSCode Settings and search for "css: enabled languages". Click in the "Edit in settings.json" link and add the following text to the json file:

```
...
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"css.enabledLanguages": ["html", "jsx"]
```

}

After doing this, press Shift+Ctrl+P and find the command "Cache CSS class definitions". This worked for me. Now I can see Bootstrap classes, for example, inside my jsx code.

Comment: settings not available in vscode 1.77.3. vscode doesn't recognize this settings. is it extension specific settings?

Comment: Yes, it is. I forgot to mention... You must install the following extensions: "IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML" and "HTML and CSS Support" . Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is necessary since most of the time, if you are using too many CSS, you are going to have modularity and have external css file. But for you, how about temporarily changing "Language Mode" to css. This may need extra clicks, but it will give you CSS auto-completions or suggestions in Visual Studio Code.